# Is the discrete or continuous-time state-space model most appropriate for implementing an embedded Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filters, embedded-systems

I'm writing down a state-space model of a mathematical pendulum, in order to estimate the system parameters in an embedded simple Kalman filter. So far I'm just modeling the system in Matlab and haven't looked into the C++/Arduino implementation.

Will it be more useful to model this as a continuous-time state-space model (as the real-world system is), or as a discrete state-space model (as the sensor samples will be discrete)?

My embedded program will read the sensors and estimate the state every 30 milliseconds. Does that make it discrete-time? The state will be used to control an LED.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My embedded program will read the sensors and estimate the state every 30 milliseconds. Does that make it discrete-time? The state will be used to control an LED. What would be an example of continuous-time prediction?

Comment: Thank you for answeing!

Comment: Anna, I'm closing this because I think this question is a duplicate of a previously asked question (that is linked above). Please read what I believe to be the dupe, and if it's not, please update your question with what is different about your situation (and flag the question for reopening once you're done).

Comment: Thank you @PeterK. ! They are indeed duplicates.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: "My embedded program will read the sensors and estimate the state every 30 milliseconds. Does that make it discrete-time?"  That would be a good question in itself, if it isn't already.  Yes -- you're sampling the system at an instant, then doing computations on that sample.  That makes it discrete time.  A continuous-time equivalent is the Kalman-Bucy filter, which, strictly speaking, you'd implement with op-amps and multipliers and whatnot.

Comment: @TimWescott That made me understand the difference, thank you! I never considered that an actual real-time filter was possible.